# magento 2 create virtual quote

Tags: magento2, quote

Can we create virtual quote and copy all current quote data into it ?
I wanna create a copy of quote data and remove or edit current quote data .
What is best solution for this

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: yes... we have two solutions.1- create a table  some of the quote table 2- create a table and save all table record as JSON into one of the columns